# How to print custom messages in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Instead of suppressing tensorflow warnings, I want to print custom warnings.

For the tensorflow warnings/messages, I'm talking about this:

[image]

How do I print my custom message in this style? And I want my custom warnings can be suppressed in a way like suppressing tensorflow warnings.

I'm using tensorflow 2.

Comment: I think those messages are going from native calls/logger, not python one. You can instance `tf.get_logger()` and use it as standard python logger.

Comment: Hi! Could you check out this thread for logging custom warnings. https://theaisummer.com/logging-debugging/